# Transaction in IndexDB does not start immediately if called after one already completed

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I'm using dexiejs to insert data in a Indexdb table(about 10k records).

After the rw transaction is completed, which I am checking with the following methods:

```
  try {
    await QDB.transaction("rw", table1, table1, async tx => {
      //ALSO CHECK TX
      tx.on("complete", () => console.log("COMPLETED"));
      //here goes the bulkadd code ...
    });
    console.log("COMPLETED");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

So after the above is completed, I then try to execute another transaction that modifies only certain records, but it takes about 20s before this last transaction even starts.

I even traced the whole process inside the chrome profiler and the browser seems relatively at ease for those 20s before the last transaction starts.

Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copying comment:

> I solved it by using only one transaction. The source of the problem
>   though was that I was using nested async function with await
>   Dexie.waitFor().  I think that using nested promises inside waitFor
>   causes the inner promises to be called with some delay

Answer (score 0):

How do you detect when the second transaction "starts" - is it when your first operation in it is resolved?

Anyhow, there might be several reasons for this. One is if you have another readonly transaction going on that blocks the next transaction from finishing. Another, I suppose, could be that the background thread that handles data processing for IndexedDB may be busy with cleanup work after a transaction has finished. If that would be the case I suppose it would not happen after every run though but more sporadically.

Comment: I know that the second transaction starts after 20 seconds because the second transaction looks like this:      
 `await QDB.transaction("rw", table1, table1, async tx => {
      console.log("starts second transaction")
  });`     This 20 seconds wait happens almost every time as usually I have to insert many records in the first transaction, and I think that is the cause of this delay

Comment: When does the COMPLETE output? You get two at the same time or one first and then the second after 20 seconds?

Comment: I get the first complete, then after 20s the second transaction starts and finishes in like 1 second and I get the second complete.

Comment: I solved it by using only one transaction.
The source of the problem though was that I was using nested async function with await Dexie.waitFor().
I think that using nested promises inside waitFor causes the inner promises to be called with some delay

Comment: Ok good you found the source of the problem. I was about to ask you whether you where using nested transactions. Dexie.waitFor() should always be used with caution and it make transactions block by design.

Comment: To clarify I was not doing nested transactions, but something like this: `await QDB.transaction("rw", table1, table1, async tx => { await Dexie.waitFor(async ()=>{await (async () =>{//implementation here})()})() })`
Because of the implementation details it was easier to split the code in multiple async functions, and potentially nest them, but I open the transaction only one time.
Thanks for the time you dedicated to this issue